# Recordset in asp and execute stored procedure in asp

Tags: asp-classic, ado

I want to open another .asp page from one .asp page on button click following is the code i have done but error is coming

Error is coming as "**operation is not allowed when the object is closed**"

Here is the code

```
 Dim dbconn, objCmd, objParam, rs, EmailID, Password, connString, RecordCount

 connString = "Connectionstring"

 dbconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")

 dbconn.Open(connString)

 rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

 objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
 objCmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
 objCmd.CommandText = "sp_Name"
 objCmd.CommandType = &H0004 
 objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@EmailID",200,1,"100",Session("EmailID"))
 objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam)

  objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@Password",200,1,"100",Session("Password"))
  objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam)

   rs = objCmd.Execute(Session("EmailID"),Session("Password"))

   do while not rs.eof ------->here comes error 

    EmailID = rs(0)
    Password =  rs(1)
    'response.Write EmailID & "," & Password & "<br">
    rs.MoveNext
loop
```

Comment: looks like your dbconn is never opened... try debugging and looking at its state... maybe something is wrong with your connString ?

Comment: Try adding `Set rs = rs.NextRecordset` before the line with error.

Comment: you should surround your do loop with

if not rs.eof Then
do while not rs.eof

loop
end if

in case of there is no record.

Answer (score 0):

try with below code.

```
SET rs = objCmd.Execute(Session("EmailID"),Session("Password"))
```

Add SET before rs

Comment: sorry SET is outdated coding

Comment: i have try it but its not working showing error as "'Let' and 'Set' assignment statements are no longer supported."

Comment: @jayu nonsense, SET is required in vbscript for assigning any object to a variable. And a recordset is an object, as is your ADODB connection, so you need SET before all statements assigning a recordset or connection. In fact, it's best practice to also clear objects from memory using Set obj = Nothing after you're done with them

Answer (score 0):

Here is my suggestion.

In my case, RecordSet object from Command.Execute() does not support .BOF nor EOF.

So, I use RecordSet.Open method to call a stored procedure like this....

```
Dim dbconn, objCmd, objParam, rs, EmailID, Password, connString, RecordCount
connString = "Connectionstring"
dbconn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
dbconn.Open(connString)

rs = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

objCmd = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCmd.ActiveConnection = dbconn
objCmd.CommandText = "sp_Name"
objCmd.CommandType = &H0004 
objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@EmailID",200,1,"100",Session("EmailID"))
objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam)
objParam = objCmd.CreateParameter("@Password",200,1,"100",Session("Password"))
objCmd.Parameters.Append(objParam)

rs.Open objCmd, dbconn, 1, 1

do while not rs.eof ------->here comes error 
    EmailID = rs(0)
    Password =  rs(1)
    'response.Write EmailID & "," & Password & "<br">
    rs.MoveNext
loop
```

I hope it's not too late!!